# Why does a VNC server seem to require valid DNS nameservers

Tags: debian, dns, vnc, x11vnc

so, I have a somewhat weird behavior of my VNC server (x11vnc on an i.mx6 based system, so ARMlev7, Debian 10). Whenever I set up DNS nameservers (in /etc/resolv.conf) which are not currently reachable (because I've got the machine disconnected from the main network and connected it to a local network with just my host PC) and then connect to the VNC server, an initial image shows but this image then freezes for about 15 seconds. Only after that do I get a realtime image. This does, however, not happen when no nameservers are specified (i.e. /etc/resolv.conf) or the nameservers can be reached from within the same network. Then, the VNC connections works fine with no delay. It seems like VNC needs proper nameservers to run.

Any idea on how I can control that behaviour? There's no guarantee that the machine will always have access to the nameservers; it may well run in another network at times, but VNC should still work normally then.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the machine has two network interfaces.

Thanks for any help.

[edit] Specifying -nolookup did the trick... Without this switch set, a reverse DNS lookup is attempted, which fails without DNS servers configured. [/edit]

Comment: Are you using a name or an IP address to connect to the other machine?

Comment: IP address only.